# Oracle SQL Query to perform Linear regression with various curve fitting techniques

Tags: sql, oracle, linear-regression

I'm trying to perform a Time Series forecast on a sample data set as below using SQL linear regression, but wanted to leverage various forms of curve fitting techniques.

```
Cust_id  Year  Revnue
1        2016  579862
1        2017  605365
1        2018  ?
2        2016  61074
2        2017  60611
2        2018  ?
3        2016  170706
3        2017  70393
3        2018  ?
4        2016  31649
4        2017  19566
4        2018  ?
```

I see something referring to Oracle `forecast()` function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1052.htm#OLADM822). Not sure how to use it though

Below are the linear regression curve fittings, I want to achieve using the Oracle SQL. Appreciate your valuable guidance/time

- Polynomial Fit: Fits data that fluctuates with a rise and a drop (x'=log(x); y'=log(y)).
- Exponential Fit: Fits data points that rise or drop at an increasingly faster rate (x'=x; y'=ln(y)).
- Logarithmic Fit: Fits data points that rise or drop quickly and then level off (x'=log(x); y'=y).
- Asymptotic Fit: Fits data points that rise or drop until they approach a fixed value and then level off (x'=1/x; y'=1/y).
- Exponential Asymptotic Fit: Fits data points that rise or drop at an increasingly faster rate until they approach a fixed value and then level off (x'=x; y'=ln(y/(K-y))).

Comment: The documentation you linked to is part of the OLAP documentation. It's only pertinent if your organisation has licensed the OLAP option and you are querying an OLAP cube.

Comment: Thank you, so there isn't any way to perform such LG model in Oracle (SQL)?

Comment: There are a bunch of linear regression functions, all prefixed with `REGR_`. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions132.htm). With luck you'll be able to make something work.